# Can python's matplotlib render images as quickly as R's Cairo device?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plotting

I need to render 100k of plots. I already am doing this quickly enough with R's Cairo device. But I am also considering using python. But, I also already know python's rendering of plots is several times slower than R's. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: According to [Cairo](https://www.cairographics.org/examples/), Matplotlib supports a Cairo backend. Also see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_cairo_api.html).

Comment: Further, you can use Cairo as a standalone. See [here](https://www.cairographics.org/samples/) for some elementary examples.

Comment: Another option is [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), which is also built on Cairo (at least in part). [Here](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/) are some examples.